# C++ Mini-program to print out randomized data pairs

Tags: c++

I basically, for this assignment, have to make a mini-program that randomly generates a string of letters based on randomized numbers (for which 0 corresponds to A, 1 corresponds to B, 2 corresponds to C, and so on) alongside with a number n corresponding to the nth string generated. These strings and their corresponding numbering are to be printed out to a text file. For example, if my function was called `myFunction`:

```
myFunction("file.txt", 3)
```

Produces a text file called "file.txt" with the following contents:

```
AAAAAAAA 1
IWFNWEFS 2
WEWEFCSD 3
```

Where the strings' letters are each supposed to be randomized.

However, for some reason each of my strings are identical for some reason. That is, for each row of string-number pairs, all the strings turn out to be the same (when I am supposed to make them all different/random). Why is this happening? Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstdlib>
#include "math.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

string key = ""; // Empty initial key for use in "makeKey".

// "makeKey" function to create an alphabetical key 
// based on 8 randomized numbers 0 - 25.
void makeKey() {
    int k;
    for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) {
        int keyNumber = (rand() % 25);
        if (keyNumber == 0)
            key.append("A");
        if (keyNumber == 1)
            key.append("B");
        if (keyNumber == 2)
            key.append("C");
        if (keyNumber == 3)
            key.append("D");
        if (keyNumber == 4)
            key.append("E");
        if (keyNumber == 5)
            key.append("F");
        if (keyNumber == 6)
            key.append("G");
        if (keyNumber == 7)
            key.append("H");
        if (keyNumber == 8)
            key.append("I");
        if (keyNumber == 9)
            key.append("J");
        if (keyNumber == 10)
            key.append("K");
        if (keyNumber == 11)
            key.append("L");
        if (keyNumber == 12)
            key.append("M");
        if (keyNumber == 13)
            key.append("N");
        if (keyNumber == 14)
            key.append("O");
        if (keyNumber == 15)
            key.append("P");
        if (keyNumber == 16)
            key.append("Q");
        if (keyNumber == 17)
            key.append("R");
        if (keyNumber == 18)
            key.append("S");
        if (keyNumber == 19)
            key.append("T");
        if (keyNumber == 20)
            key.append("U");
        if (keyNumber == 21)
            key.append("V");
        if (keyNumber == 22)
            key.append("W");
        if (keyNumber == 23)
            key.append("X");
        if (keyNumber == 24)
            key.append("Y");
        if (keyNumber == 25)
            key.append("Z");
    }
    return;
}

// "makeFile" function to produce the desired text file.
// Note this only works as intended if you include the ".txt" extension,
// and that a file of the same name doesn't already exist.
void makeFile(string fileName, int n) {
    ofstream ourFile;
    ourFile.open(fileName);
    int k; // For use in below loop to compare with n.
    int l; // For use in the loop inside the below loop.
    for (k = 1; k <= n; k++) {
        for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) {  // To write to the file ONE key
        ourFile << key[l];         // C++ only lets me do it this way...
        }
        ourFile << "  " << k << "\n"; // Writes two spaces and the data value
    }
}

// Primary function to create our desired file!
void mainFunction(string fileName, int n) {
    makeKey();
    makeFile(fileName, n);
}

int main() {
    mainFunction("file.txt", 3); // To test program
    cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

I tried using both `srand ( time(NULL) );` and `srand (1);` in the first part, but that didn't work for me either.

Comment: This is working way too hard.  Build an array of characters (which is just a string) and use a random number as the index into the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each time you call `makeKey`, it appends 8 more characters to the end of `key`, but you never clear out the previous contents, and after calling `makeKey`, you print out the first 8 characters, which haven't changed.

I'd get rid of the global variable `key`, and have `makeKey` return a (newly created) `std::string` every time it's called.

FWIW, I'd also rewrite `makeKey` to convert from numbers to letters by indexing into an array of char.

Edit (In response to the edit in the question): Yes, you probably also want to use `srand(time(NULL));` at the beginning of the program. `srand(1);` is the same as if you didn't bother to call `srand` at all. Using `srand(time(NULL));` should normally give a different sequence of results every time you run the program (unless you run it twice so quickly that the system clock doesn't change in between -- normally twice in the same second).

Right now you're getting one string repeated 8 times. Fixing the problem noted above will give you 8 different strings -- but without something like `srand(time(NULL));`, you'll get the same group of 8 strings ever time you run the program. If you just add `srand(time(NULL));` and don't fix the rest, you'll get one string 8 times, but it'll be a different one each time you run the program (whereas right now, even the one string you get will be the same as every other time you run the program).

Comment: If I got rid of the global variable, wouldn't my other functions not work anymore since they all refer to key?

Comment: @forthewinwin: Yes, you'd have to rewrite them a bit to refer to the return value from `makeKey`. Using something like `std::string key = makeKey();` (continuing to use the same name) would minimize the changes you'd make to the other code though.

Comment: Where would I use string `key = makeKey();` ? I tried inserting it above `makeFile`, getting rid of the global variable `key` I originally declared at the top, and having `makeKey` return `key`, but it's still giving me the same problem. I think it has to do with my makeFile using the same `key` in the inner loop, but I'm not sure how I'd rewrite everything then.

Comment: @forthewinwin: You'll probably need some modification to both `mainFunction and `makeFile`.

Comment: I think it has to do with my makeFile using the same key in the inner loop, but I'm not sure how I'd rewrite everything then. Tried making `makeFile` call `makeKey` again to make a new key after each loop, but that's not working either :(

Comment: @forthewinwin: Okay, to be more explicit: I'd probably eliminate `mainFunction` completely, and call `makeKey` once during each iteration of the loop in `makeFile`.

Comment: Tried that, and made makeFile call makeKey at the end of every loop, but in fact now it's worse: just prints one letter now for all my rows.

Comment: @forthewinwin: `makeFile` should basically do something like: `for i=1 to 8 do: name = makeKey(); print(file, name); enddo`.

Comment: I noticed that if I took out the srand clause, I won't have the problem of having 8 identical letters in one string anymore, but each of my rows of strings are identical. Including the srand clause makes ALL the letters the same for some reason.

Comment: EDIT: Got it to work perfectly now after taking OUT the srand clause and inserting it at the beginning of my `main` function instead and having `makeKey();` at the end of my outermost for-loop in `makeFile`... wierd lol